# Trying to use persistent data across sessions

Tags: python, sqlite, data-access-layer

I am trying to access persistent data saved in an SQLite database file without wiping it. I start an interactive session with Python without Web2py and enter :

```
from pydal import DAL, Field

db = DAL('sqlite://storage.sqlite', folder='home/cryptoj/venv', auto_import=True)

db.define_table('persons', Field('name'))
```

Now I can create and save table data. After `db.commit()` the table is saved and I can read it with DB Browser for SQLite. I can enter additional data from DB Browser and it too can be read in the interactive Python session.

I close the terminal and DB Browser. Then I open DB Browser and the data is all there. Yet, when I go through the above commands, in a new session it appears the `db.define_table` is dropping the data stored in storage.sqlite.

On the 2nd time opening a new terminal, if I don't `define_table` again there are errors and the existing data can not be read in the interactive session.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need the option `migrate` set to `False`

```
self.db.define_table('persons', Field('name'), migrate=False)
```